# How to get all threads of the inbox using the Graph API in IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook-graph-api

at the moment I am trying to implement the Facebook API in one of my iOS Apps.
But now I have a small problem.

I can access my user information or my friend list but I have a problem to get all my objects of my inbox. Of course I set the access token. But now I don't know how to get the messages (or called threads in Facebook see: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/thread/)

```
- (NSArray*) getUserMessages {
   NSArray *result = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"test", nil];
   [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/threads" andDelegate:self];
   return result;
}
```

I also get a callback of my delegate method:

```
- (void) request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
  NSLog(@"%@", [result description]);
}
```

I would be kind if someone could help me!

Best regards

xen

Comment: What is facebook returning as response of that request?

Answer (score 0):

necessarily set "read_mailbox" in read permissions

-(void)readFBMessages{

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/threads"
                             parameters:nil
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(
                                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error
                                          ) {
                          self.tableData = result[@"data"];
                          [self.tableSearch reloadData];
                      }];
```

}